# How to use cin "as a parameter" in a switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement, cin

I want to be able to create a switch statement using cin, without having to create a variable to store the value inputed. For example:

```
switch(cin){
case 1: std::cout << "Hello World";
break;
default:
break;
}
```

Comment: You could use: `switch ( std::cin.get() ) {` and then `case 49:` or `case '1':`

Comment: Hmmmm: `switch([]{int i; std::cin >> i; return i;}()){ ...`

Comment: @RichardCritten I like that ^_^

Comment: @RichardCritten even easier with C++17: `switch (int n; std::cin >> n, n) { ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I want to be able to create a switch statement using cin ?* No you can't as `switch` expects only `integral` quantity but `cin`  is object of class. From n4296 section 6.4

> switch ( condition ) statement
>
> The value of a `condition` that is an initialized declaration in a
>   `switch` statement is the value of the declared variable if it has
>   `integral` or `enumeration` type, or of that variable implicitly converted
>   to integral or enumeration type otherwise. The value of a condition
>   that is an expression is the value of the expression, contextually
>   converted to `bool` for statements other than switch; if that conversion
>   is ill-formed, the program is ill-formed.

`switch(cin)` results in error for the reason I mentioned above but you can use any method which returns `integer` like `cin.get()` for e.g

```
switch(std::cin.get()) {
   /*... */
}
```